# SQL2012 alwayson,read-only route's not work

Tags: sql-server

i have 3 nodes as S2,S3,S4
and S3 is the primary server, S2 is secondary server, S4 is readonly server(i made it)
and the alwayson Availabilty Grps work without any problem.

i had configuration read/wirte and read route like this below

[image]

my db connection code is:

```
Data Source=tcp:[listener IP]; Initial Catalog=[DB NAME]; User ID=sa;
Password=sa;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;MultiSubnetFailover=True;
```

i run my program, it always run at primary server

[image]

how should i do?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a few reasons causing the read-only request to not route to S4.

First of all, let's make sure we're in the same page:

When you use SSMS to connect to the listener, did you ever change the connection options? If you didn't, then the connection will not be connected using the routing table.

To verify, please launch SSMS, and try to connect to server:

Put the listener name and port number, then before clicking the `Connect` button, notice there's an `Options` button, click it.

Did you see any thing there? If it was blank, you need to put the following parameter there:

```
 “ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly”
```

Then you can use `select @@servername` to verify if you're routing to a readonly node.

Please let me know if that answered your question.

--cheers!